# Node.js just returns "..." in terminal

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm a front end dev trying to learn and get into Node.js

Having trouble at the first hurdle. I have an app.js file in the root of Mac: "/"
app.js has the following:

```
console.log('hello world!');
```

Whenever I run node app.js in the terminal I get the following:

```
> node app.js
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running the Node.js REPL first.  Don't do that... the Node.js REPL is for running immediate evaluations.

Just try running `node app.js` from your normal system terminal.

Comment: That worked! 

However, it still won't run the http server as per the getting started example on the node site.

`var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');`

Comment: @samjhiggins Post a new question for that and explain what is/isn't happening.  Maybe you have something else listening on that port already.